# Add column with coordinates in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, geolocation

I am new to programming in Python/Pyspark, so I am sorry if it is a basic question.

I have dataframe with addresses. However, note that not all of them are correctly spelled.

```
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+
|index| Country|City             |      date|
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+
|    1|  NL    |Staphorst        |2017-01-01|
|    2|  BE    |Herselt-Blauwberg|2017-01-02|
|    3|  NL    |Oosterend        |2017-01-03|
|    4|  BL    |Hoogezand        |2017-01-04|
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+
```

It can be created with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "NL", 'Staphorst', '2017-01-01'),
        (2, 'BE', 'Herselt-Blauwberg', '2017-01-02'),
        (3, "NL", 'Oosterend', '2017-01-03'),
        (4, "NL", 'Hoogezand', '2017-01-04')
    ],
    ('index', 'Country', 'City', 'date')
)
```

I want to know the coordinates for all adressess. If the city/address is mispelled I just want it to be empty. So the desired outcome would look something like:

```
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+
|index| Country|City             |      date| lat             | lon               | 
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+
|    1|  NL    |Staphorst        |2017-01-01|6.208129803185402|52.636838749999995 |
|    2|  BE    |Herselt-Blauwberg|2017-01-02|                 |                   |
|    3|  NL    |Oosterend        |2017-01-03|4.8731736        |53.0857473         |
|    4|  BL    |Hoogezand        |2017-01-04|6.7556852        |53.1638192         |
+-----+--------+-----------------+----------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

I tried using geopy. The code kind of works when I turn my df into a pandas dataframe (see below). However, I have trouble extracting the latitude en longitude data (as it isn't always available) and on my actual dataframe it takes way too long to run.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_app")

df1 = df.toPandas()
df1['geo'] = df1['City'].apply(geolocator.geocode)
df1
```

Hence I would prefer a pyspark alternative. I tried using a primitive way to get the code working in pyspark, but again it takes forever to run as I use a loop and the coordinates end up in a seperate list, which I don't like as I would like to keep everything together.

```
longitude = []
latitude = []

for i in range(len(df.select("City").collect())):          
      loc = geolocator.geocode(df.select("City").collect()[i].City)
        
      if loc != None:
        latitude.append(loc.latitude)
        longitude.append(loc.longitude)
      else:
        latitude.append("")
        longitude.append("")
```

I though I should probably write an UDF, but I failed in getting it to work. My attempt so far:

```
def geo_loc(str_x):
  loc = geolocator.geocode(str_x)
  if loc != None:
    return loc
  else: 
    return ""

geo_locUDF = udf(lambda z:geo_loc(z), StringType()) 

df.withColumn("geo", geo_locUDF(col('City')))
```

Could someone help me finding the correct coordinates?

edit: sprak.version returns 3.1.0, in case that is relevant.

Comment: What's your spark version?

Comment: @Kafels Using Databricks, spark.version returns 3.1.0. So  I guess 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, someone removed their answer even though they helped me in the right direction. The code they gave me was the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

nominatim = Nominatim(user_agent="my_app")
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "NL", 'Staphorst', '2017-01-01'),
        (2, 'BE', 'Herselt-Blauwberg', '2017-01-02'),
        (3, "NL", 'Oosterend', '2017-01-03'),
        (4, "NL", 'Hoogezand', '2017-01-04')
    ],
    ('index', 'Country', 'City', 'date')
)


@f.udf(returnType='STRUCT<`Latitude`: double, `Longitude`: double>')
def search(country, city):
    location = nominatim.geocode(query={'country': country, 'city': city}, timeout=60)
    if location is None:
        return {'Latitude': None, 'Longitude': None}
    else:
        return {'Latitude': location.latitude, 'Longitude': location.longitude}


geocode_df = (df
              .select('Country', 'City')
              .distinct()
              .withColumn('Geo', search('Country', 'City')))

new_df = df.join(geocode_df, on=['Country', 'City'], how='inner')
(new_df
 .select('Country', 'City', 'Geo.Latitude', 'Geo.Longitude')
 .show(truncate=False))
```

This worked for that person but in Databricks I got an error. Basically saying `has no attribute 'Request sHTTPWithSSLContextAdapter__ ssl_context'`

I googled that again today and [found a more recent question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871440/attributeerror-requestshttpwithsslcontextadapter-object-has-no-attribute-re) where someone pointed out that the creation of the nominatim context should be in the UDF. Probably rookie mistake but I am happy my UDF now runs!