# AttributeError: 'RequestsHTTPWithSSLContextAdapter' object has no attribute '_RequestsHTTPWithSSLContextAdapter__ssl_context'

Tags: pyspark, databricks, reverse-geocoding, geopy, nominatim

I am performing reverse geocoding i.e converting coordinates to city by using geopy's Nominatim locator in pyspark. I packed it inside a function getCity() which takes a pair of coords in string and returns the city. For example:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
def getCity(coords):

  loc = locator.reverse(coords, language="en")
  try:
    city = loc.raw["address"]["city"]
  except:
    city = '' if loc is None else loc.raw["address"].get('state', '') # if couldn't find city then return state, otherwise just empty string
  return city
```

This function works fine if mapped to a pandas dataframe column but throws exception in pyspark. I have tried pyspark's withColumn, spark UDFs and even converted to rdd for this mapping but the same exception gets returned i.e

```
UDF_getCity  = F.udf(getCity, StringType())
cityDF_spark = cityDF_spark.select('geom', UDF_getCity('geom').alias('CITY'))
cityDF_spark.show()
```

PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'RequestsHTTPWithSSLContextAdapter' object has no attribute '_RequestsHTTPWithSSLContextAdapter__ssl_context'

Comment: check versions of the libraries used & how they are attached to a cluster

Comment: Nominatim instance must be created inside your UDF function, because it cannot be serialized and be reused on another machine.

Comment: @KostyaEsmukov You are a bloody hero. I asked this question previously on stackoverflow without succes. I added the creation of the nominatim instance inside my UDF and it solved all problem. THANK YOU!!!